# phantomjs output weird characters

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, prerender

I've installed prerender.io on Xampp, I did nothing fancy. Just installed the everything prerender needs and followed the documentation on [prerender.io](http://prerender.io) and https://github.com/zf-fr/zfr-prerender. 
So lets say I've put prerender over here:

```
/public/assets/services/prerender
```

and in the console I ran:

```
npm install
node server.js
```

Zfr-prerender is the middleware and I only changed one thingy, the url that refers to prerender:

```
'prerender_url' => 'http://localhost:3000/public/assets/services/prerender',
```

In my browser I go to:

> local host/shop/api/list?_escaped_fragment_=

The router from angularJS redirect to /list/1 when there is no route found:

```
ListerApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
$routeProvider
    .when('/list/:page?',
        {
            templateUrl : '/assets/services/partials/list.html',
            controller : 'ListerCtrl',
            reloadOnSearch : false,
            js : ['/assets/min/shoplist_js.min.js', '/assets/min/bootstrap-typeahead.min.js'],
            //css : [],
            resolve : {
                sharedServiceAppData: function($sharedData){
                    // sharedFactoryAppData will also be injectable in your controller, if you don't want this you could create a new promise with the $q service
                    return $sharedData.promise();
                    //return;
                }
            }
        }
    )
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/list/1' });
```

}]);

The console is telling me this:

```
getting public/assets/services/prerender/http://localhost/shop/api/list
got 200 in 419ms for public/assets/services/prerender/http://localhost/shop/api/list
```

But all that phantomJS returns are weird characters.

```
public function prerenderPost(PrerenderEvent $event)
{
    // This is the response we get from the Prerender service
    $response = $event->getResponse();
    var_dump($response->getHeaders());
    var_dump($response->getContent());
    // You could get the body and put it in cache
    // ...

}
```

These are the headers, var_dump($response->getHeaders()):

```
 array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Content-Type' (length=12)
      'line' => string 'Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8' (length=37)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Content-Encoding' (length=16)
      'line' => string 'Content-Encoding: gzip' (length=22)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Content-Length' (length=14)
      'line' => string 'Content-Length: 45' (length=18)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Date' (length=4)
      'line' => string 'Date: Thu, 30 Oct 2014 18:23:39 GMT' (length=35)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Connection' (length=10)
      'line' => string 'Connection: close'
```

This is a PHP var_dump($response->getContent()):

> string '‹������³É(ÉÍ±³ÉHML±³Ñ‡PIù)•@”+�� ’H'���' (length=45)
>
> ‹³É(ÉÍ±³ÉHML±³Ñ‡PIù)•@”+ ’H'

Comment: This should probably be a detailed bug report here https://github.com/zf-fr/zfr-prerender/issues or here https://github.com/prerender/prerender/issues

Comment: Yeah, a little more info on what you did (and which URL you accessed) to get those characters would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit this question so there is more info. And I'll post it on github issues. We (or me) could refer to the github discussion later on so people might find more info about this question here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to unzip and get the content you'll need

```
$response->getBody()
```

Second of all, it might be useful to increase the socket timeout in de Zfr-prenderer module in case you have a very very old and slow computer.